# Sinatra converting backslash to forward slash

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra, backslash

The JSON I'm posting to my webserver looks like this:

```
"qry_when":["date_is_in(\"X:\\Finqueries\\Dates\\earnings files\\earnings.wmt.txt\")"]
```

but in my sinatra code,

```
apost '/parsequery/*' do 
  data = params[:captures][0]
```

`data` looks like

```
"qry_when":["date_is_in(/"X:/Finqueries/Dates/earnings files/earnings.wmt.txt/")"]
```

Because the `\"` is getting turned into `/"`, when I later call `JSON.parse(data)`, I get a parsing error:

> unexpected token at 'X:/Finqueries/Dates/earnings files/earnings.wmt.txt/")"]

Is there anyway to get Sinatra to *not* convert the backslashes to forward slashes?

`EDIT:` As a solution, I have javascript change all my `"\"` to `%5C` and single and double quotes to `%27` before sending the json, and it's working now in both chrome and opera.

Comment: I doubt that Sinatra is changing single and double backslashes to a single forward-slash in request parameters. There's probably something else going on here, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: I think you're right, as "early" as I can catch the data (in the `thin` library files), it always shows the forward slash version.

Comment: Perhaps it's something happening on the client-side then?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: it definitely is.  when I run it in chrome, I get what I originally described. when I run it in opera, it works fine, i.e., it's not changing the `\`'s to `/`'s.  Thanks for following up, btw.

Comment: Found this: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25916, which explains how Chrome handles backslashes.  Opera actually does the conversion to `%5c`, which works fine when received by the server.

Comment: Note that that's a duplicate of [bug 45051](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45051). And it also seems to only be about the URL, but you said in your question that you're using a POST request.

Comment: When I inspected what sinatra was receiving, what I was posting was listed as part of the url.  Here's a snippet of the code:         `$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:    '/parsequery/' + jsonQuery,`
where "jsonQuery" is the json text.

Comment: As a solution, I have javascript change all my `"\"` to `%5C` and single and double quotes to `%27` before sending the json,  and it's working now in both chrome and opera.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you should either post your answer below, which you can accept after 48 hours, or, if you think your question/answer are of no relevance to future visitors, you can delete your question entirely. You should *not* simply edit your question with the solution.